# Make current tab control page visible when the main form is refreshed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have forms with various sub forms and tab control pages. A combo box is used to navigate the records in the entire form. Whenever the value is changed from the combo box or from the navigation buttons, the first tab control page is always visible. I want to make the current tab control page to be visible whenever the form is refreshed. any help how to do so please?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for setting the tab: Me.TabControlName.Pages.Item(PageIndexNumber).SetFocus

Event for form refresh: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193159.aspx

Short version - put this in your form's code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

Me.TabControlName.Pages.Item(0).SetFocus

End Sub
```

When the form is refreshed the Form_Current event will fire and execute your code. Since you want the first tab to be visible the Item index is 0. Replace TabControlName with the name of your control.

Comment: Syntax: Me.TabControlName.Pages.Item(PageIndexNumber).SetFocus is ok, but its difficult to use as I may not know on which page Number I will be working at the time the form is refreshed. 

The link for current event is great, I understand the theory buy my apology I cant get any idea how do I code.  

Any syntax help would be appreciated please.

Comment: I've expanded my answer. Do have a good read through the msdn link though - all the answers are there!